# Why do I get the console error `Invalid config, unrecognized key .streaming.jumpLargeGaps` when streaming content?

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

Whenever I stream content to my web receiver, I receive a console error stating `Invalid config, unrecognised key .streaming.jumpLargeGaps`. I am not setting this key in the [PlaybackConfig.shakaConfig](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver/cast.framework.PlaybackConfig#shakaConfig). I am not setting the `shakaConfig` at all.

I receive this console error in both my main web receiver application and a barebones web receiver I made to sanity check that it's a general problem. I searched the internet but couldn't find any discussion of this problem.

The default Cast SDK Shaka Player version, 4.3.4, which I am using, doesn't support this key in its [StreamingConfiguration](https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/shaka.extern.html#.StreamingConfiguration).

My guess would be that this is included in the Cast SDK's default Shaka Player config, accidentally left in from when the Cast SDK updated the default Shaka Player version.

Is there any way to fix this? I don't think it's negatively affecting playback, but I would like to remove this incorrect config if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug into the (at the time of writing) current version of the [Web Receiver Cast SDK (3.0.0111)](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes#july-6,-2023) and console logged where it was calling `.configure(...)` for the Shaka Player. With no overrides, this is the object passed to `.configure(...)`:

```
{
  abr: {
    defaultBandwidthEstimate: 2000000,
  },
  drm: {
    retryParameters: {
      maxAttempts: 4,
      baseDelay: 400,
      backoffFactor: 2,
      timeout: 30000,
    },
    servers: {
      'com.widevine.alpha':
        'https://manifest.prod.boltdns.net/license/v1/cenc/widevine/963482467001/8c52050a-58f6-45cd-b5d7-251739fe7c57/bc1e2935-71b7-476b-93ac-f48a62cc9b94?fastly_token=NjU5MzM2YzFfYWZjOTAzOTMwMWM3MmEzY2Q3NzIyZDRmZTY2YmFjYzRiZjU0NTBhMDlhNjQyMmIzZTk5MjU2MGE0ZjFjZmJlZQ%3D%3D',
    },
    advanced: {
      'com.widevine.alpha': {
        audioRobustness: 'HW_SECURE_CRYPTO',
        videoRobustness: 'HW_SECURE_ALL',
      },
    },
  },
  manifest: {
    retryParameters: {
      maxAttempts: 4,
      baseDelay: 400,
      backoffFactor: 2,
      timeout: 30000,
    },
  },
  streaming: {
    jumpLargeGaps: true,
    rebufferingGoal: 10,
    retryParameters: {
      maxAttempts: 4,
      baseDelay: 400,
      backoffFactor: 2,
      timeout: 30000,
    },
    stallThreshold: 5,
  },
};
```

As you can see, the `streaming.jumpLargeGaps` is set to `true`. The default Shaka Player version in the current Cast SDK is 4.3.4, which does not have this configuration option. It must've been left over. Nothing I can do about it, I guess.